# Adding Movie Clip to UI Component in flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

I am working on a code where i am using loader to add movie clip to UI Component but I dont' want to use loader. Is there any other way to add movie clip to UIComponent??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html). Either place one inside your UIComponent, or if the MovieClip is the only thing inside the UIComponent, you can use the SWFLoader instead of the UIComponent.

Use the load method to load a SWF or an image, eg:

```
mySWFLoader.load("path/to/the/movie.swf");
```

If you don't want to load at runtime, you can embed the SWF in the Flex app instead. And in this case you only need an Image component with the source property set. eg:

```
<mx:Image id="myImage" source="@Embed(source='path/to/the/movie.swf')" />
```

Comment: Hi, I am using SWFLoader already, but i don't want to use that. Is there any other way to do so??

Comment: My Movie clip will be having around 10 frames. If i will use Image then how will i change the frames? and actually i want to load at runtime but without using SWFLoader. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to control the movieclip from the Flex app, the easiest way is with SWFLoader. Why dont you want to use it?